# VBA Excel macro - display cell values which are column related

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get unique values from column **P** and display them in the column **Q** (so far i know how to do that):

```
s1.Range("P2:P").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=x3No
```

[image: Excell sheet]

But i can't figure out how to display values ( column **O** ) of those id's into the column **R** . Duplicate id's have the same values. That each unique id would have only one value. Could anyone help me a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just remove duplicates using the range `O2:P10`?

Comment: @BigBen thanks for reply, i somehow thought this should be harder, but simplicity always wins :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
Sub test()

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

s1.Range("O2:R100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes 'remove duplicates from column 2 in range O2:R100

lrow = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row.

For i = 2 To lrow
    Cells(i, 18).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value 'Copy values
Next i
End Sub
```

---

Instead of removing the previous values from the column O and P I would just fill the unique id and value columns with unique values.

```
Sub test()

Dim unique()
Dim ct As Long
Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

Set s1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

ReDim unique(s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row)

lrow = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Find first row to fill with unique values


For x = 2 To s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row 'Column to check for unique values
    If CountIfArray(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 16), unique()) = 0 Then 'Build array to store unique values.
        unique(ct) = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 16).Text 'Populate the array
        Cells(lrow, 17).Value = Cells(x, 16).Value 'Copy column P to Q
        Cells(lrow, 18).Value = Cells(x, 15).Value  'Copy column O to R
        lrow = lrow + 1
        ct = ct + 1 
    End If
Next x
End Sub

Public Function CountIfArray(lookup_val As String, lookup_arr As Variant)
CountIfArray = Application.Count(Application.Match(lookup_val, lookup_arr, 0))
End Function
```